# SyntaxError when using function onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a function which works as excepted when called from the console but when I use it in button `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Function:

```js
function changeById(className, newHTML) {
  document.getElementById(className).innerHTML = newHTML;
  document.getElementById(className).style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeById(" liele ", "Example text ")">Click me</button>
```

Comment: It's probably the double quotes. Try `onclick="changeById('liele', 'Example text')"`

Comment: @slider Thanks, didn't know that there is a difference in quotes in js

Comment: There's no difference, but in this case you want the `onclick` value to be the entire string `changeById("liele", "Example text")` but if you use double quotes to start the string and you have double quotes *inside* the string, only a part of the string is considered (`onclick="changeById("`) which is wrong.

Comment: @MarkAlanFrank Actually it's about how the quotes work in HTML, it has nothing to do with JS. The attribute is `onclick="changeById("`. You will need to escape them according to HTML rules, with `&quot;` - or by changing them to `'`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape your inner quotes or use single quotes on the inside might work.

`"changeById(' liele ', 'Example text ')"`

`"changeById(\" liele \", \"Example text \")"`